# CardStackLayoutManager restart when adapter updated

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I'm implementing a list using CardStackLayoutManager. My problem is that when i i reach the last item of the list, i call a method to get other elements, but when I update the adapter (using `update()` function), the list starts from the first position, and not from the one i have arrived to.
The Adapter it self should not have problems, since I use the same logic with basic RecyclerView and I don't have this problem, so i don't know if I have to change something to adapt it to the CardStackLayoutManager.

CardStackLayoutManager lib: https://github.com/yuyakaido/CardStackView

This is the Adapter:

```
class Adapter(private val items: MutableList<EstimationModel>) :
        RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder>() {

        fun update(list: MutableList<EstimationModel>) {
            this.items.addAll(list)
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

        fun clearList() = items.clear()

        fun getPage(): Int = (items.size / BuildConfig.PAGE_SIZE)

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(
            parent: ViewGroup,
            viewType: Int
        ): ViewHolder {
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_estimation, parent, false)
            return ViewHolder(view)
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
            holder.bindItem(items[position])
        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int = items.size

        class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
            fun bindItem(item: EstimationModel) {
                val date = Date(item.lastModifiedDate!!)
                val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy", Locale.getDefault())

                itemView.item_history_date.text = sdf.format(date)

                itemView.item_history_list.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(itemView.context)
                itemView.item_history_list.setHasFixedSize(true)
                itemView.item_history_list.adapter = ItemAdapter(item.estimationCatalogs)
            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT: Solution**

I edited to update function to this, and the problem solved. Hope this will help someone:

```
fun update(list: MutableList<EstimationModel>) {
            this.items.addAll(list)
            notifyItemRangeInserted(items.size - list.size, list.size)
        }
```